# Recent change in create Dataset from Datastore UI?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm working on the new feature "Data Drift in Azure ML", but I had problems when I was testing this tool, the interface to create Datasets from Datastore is not like the documentation, is it different?.

Also, when I try using format partition like the documentation, the configuration shows me some errors, it only works with this format `/{datetime}/filename.cvs` instead of `/{timestamp:yyyy/MM/dd}/filename.csv`, and the schema section doesn't display the schema like in the documentation.

Comment: Were you able to create the dataset but the petitioning did not work are you blocked from creating the dataset? Can you share some screenshots to describe your issue? I'd suggest reviewing the inline description for the partition feature: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfpoR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfpoR.png) Lastly, let us know if you run into issues with trying out Drift.... Manoj, AzureML team

Comment: following up for manoj's comment above. It will be great to share your folder structure so that we can help you with the right partition format to specify